# Fast algorithm for Transportation Problem in Python?

Tags: optimization, python, network-flow, computational-complexity

The Transportation Problem can be solved with a simplex algorithm, but it's time-consuming.

I'm wondering if there exists a specific Python-implemented algorithm with low complexity.

Comment: I’m having the same question now.... which algorithms did you end up using?

Comment: There are several efficient algorithms to solve besides simplex. Could you provide more details about the kind of constraints you have and the size of your problem?

Comment: I'd expect [OptaPy](https://www.optapy.org) (open source) to work well on the Transportation Problem too, but I haven't tried it yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could try to solve it as a min cost flow problem.

NetworkX is a package for graph algorithms and has algorithms for this implemented.
It can easily be installed via `pip install networkx`.

An minimal working example is given at the bottom of this link:

https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-2.4/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.flow.min_cost_flow.html#networkx.algorithms.flow.min_cost_flow

Answer (score 2):

You can try [CBC](https://github.com/coin-or/Cbc) which uses Dual Simplex (the same algorithm CPLEX & GUROBI use). The easiest way to use that through Python is [Pyomo](http://www.pyomo.org/).

Comment: It might be even easier to do it through PuLP. By installing PuLP you get the installation of CBC "for free". I prefer to model using Pyomo though

Answer (score -1):

I personally use `networkx` some example of transportation modelling from networkx is available in my article [here](https://medium.com/towards-data-science/spatial-data-science-network-analysis-for-transportation-planning-7be048b8f37?source=user_profile---------2----------------------------).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).